# aws-sdk-cpp: How to access S3 through Proxy?

Tags: c++, proxy, aws-sdk-cpp

I have environment variables, eg. HTTPS_PROXY, set.  I can simply do `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/key..` to list S3 through proxy.

How can I achieve the same in aws-sdk-cpp?

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out myself, here is an example

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration cconfig;
cconfig.proxyHost = "localhost";
cconfig.proxyPort = 1234;
cconfig.proxyScheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTPS;
Aws::S3::S3Client(cconfig);
```